# JavaMelody monitoring page with Content Encoding Error in Firefox

Tags: firefox, grails, java-melody

Recently I added [JavaMelody](https://code.google.com/p/javamelody/wiki/UserGuide#Setup) plugin to my site, but when I try to load in Firefox I got this message:

> Content Encoding Error
>
> The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression.
>     Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.

There is a lot of information about that like clean cookies and cache, change **network.http.accept-encoding** value to **true**, etc. but when I run the project in  development with Groovy/Grails Tools Suite this error does not appear.
Because that I try different solutions and I found that there is not need to change Firefox properties. You need to follow the [web.xml](https://code.google.com/p/javamelody/wiki/UserGuide#2._web.xml_file) file setup but pay attention where you add this lines.

There are three elements: **filter**, **filter-mapping** and **listener**. You need to add each element in the first position in the relevant section, for example:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" metadata-complete="true" version="2.5" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<display-name>/myweb</display-name>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
    <param-value>myweb</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>sample</param-name>
    <param-value>Sample Value</param-value>
</context-param>
<!-- filter javamelody first -->
<filter>
            <filter-name>monitoring</filter-name>
            <filter-class>net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

<filter>
    <!-- other filters -->
</filter>

<!-- filter-mapping javamelody first -->
    <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>monitoring</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <!-- others filter-mappings -->
</filter-mapping>

<!-- listener javamelody first -->
    <listener>
            <listener-class>net.bull.javamelody.SessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

<listener>
 <!-- others listeners here -->
</listener>
<!-- others lines like servlets, etc -->
```

I have no more information but I think there is an order reading encoding in differents elements in this web.xml.

I hope it help, but feel free to add more information.